# gradle custom task order on Android

Tags: android, build, gradle, build-automation

I have 2 gradle tasks that i want to run after `assembleRelease` task.

```
task copyRequiredFilesToVersionControl(type:Copy) {
  ...
}

task ('versionControl') << {
  ...
}
```

If I configure order for these tasks as below tasks get never called...

```
copyRequiredFilesToVersionControl.dependsOn(assembleRelease)
versionControl.dependsOn(copyRequiredFilesToVersionControl)
```

If i change order like;

```
assembleRelease.dependsOn(copyRequiredFilesToVersionControl)
versionControl.dependsOn(copyRequiredFilesToVersionControl)
```

Tasks are run at the beginning of document. So there is no file to copy and add to version control.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found method that called doLast. So i fixed my problem with it.

```
assembleRelease {
    doLast {
        tasks.versionControl.execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with gradle-experimental.  I get an error: `assembleRelease Object [*]
[*] - indicates that a model item could not be found for the path or type.`

Answer (score 1):

The best approach that I've found to date, has been to use the Ordering Tasks feature in Gradle : see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html for more documentation, currently section 15.5.

Basically, you have two rules available : MUST run after and SHOULD run after. I like the rule quite a bit, I use this to create zip archives of projects automatically.  NOTE : you must still make use of the "dependsOn" to get proper execution if tasks that you need to have run in a particular order.